# Doctrine ORM: type-hinting for aggregated values

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I use a few Value Object types in the ORM mapping (DateTime, Money, etc) and sometimes I need to get an aggregated value (SUM, MIN, AVG, etc) for them.

For example:

```
namespace App\Entity;

/** @ORM\Entity **/
class Foo {
  /** 
   * @var \DateTime
   *
   * @ORM\Column(type="datetime") 
   */
   protected $date;
}
```

`SELECT MAX(f.date) AS max_date FROM App\Entity\Foo f` - hydrates to a string rather than a DateTime object

```
/** @ORM\Entity **/
class Bar {
  /** 
   * @var \Money\Money
   *
   * @ORM\Column(type="money") 
   */
   protected $moneyAmount;
}
```

`SELECT SUM(b.moneyAmount) AS total FROM App\Entity\Bar b` - hydrates to a string rather than a Money object

Regardless of what method I use to fetch the result (`getResult`, `getArrayResult`, `getSingleResult`, `getSingleScalarResult`, etc), the aggregated value itself is always a string.

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["max_date"]=>
    string(19) "2020-09-10 06:43:33"
  }
}
```

Currently, I have to convert the result to an object by hand:

```
$maxDateString = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
$maxDate = new DateTime($maxDateString);
```

But it would be great to leverage the `convertToPHPValue` method of existing DBAL types.

So I was wondering if it's possible to specify a mapping type for an aggregated value so that it's hydrated as `DateTime`, or `Money`, or at least the same type as the aggregated field itself is.